# Timing a Python Program

Tags: python, timing

I have an optimization program that generates 150 different lineups and right now the way I have it set up is it tells me how long the program took to run after completion. How would I display how much time is left to complete or how many lineups are left to complete?

```
import pulp
from pulp import *
from pulp.solvers import CPLEX_PY
from pydfs_lineup_optimizer import get_optimizer, Site, Sport,CSVLineupExporter
from pydfs_lineup_optimizer.solvers.pulp_solver import PuLPSolver
import time
start_time = time.time()
class CustomPuLPSolver(PuLPSolver):
    LP_SOLVER = pulp.CPLEX_PY(msg=0)
optimizer = get_optimizer(Site.FANDUEL, Sport.BASEBALL, solver=CustomPuLPSolver)

optimizer.load_players_from_csv("/Users/austi/Desktop/MLB/PLAYERS_LIST.csv")
optimizer.restrict_positions_for_opposing_team(['P'], ['1B','C','2B','3B','SS','OF','UTIL'])
optimizer.set_team_stacking([2,2,2]) #Stacking should change according to slate size...still need to figure that out
optimizer.set_max_repeating_players(4)
optimizer.set_spacing_for_positions(['SS','C','1B','3B','OF','2B'], 4)
lineups = list(optimizer.optimize(n=150))
for lineup in lineups:
    print(lineup)
exporter = CSVLineupExporter(lineups)
exporter.export('MLB_result.csv')
print(round(((time.time() - start_time)/60)), "minutes run time")
```

Comment: You'd have to figure it out -- this is quite a difficuilt computer science problem. You'd have to somehow measure the average time of each operation so far, and then work out the fraction of operations completed and work the time remaining out from that. Depending on your code/algorithms, that might not be possible.

Comment: Check out the `tqdm` package. You may be able to either use it, or let it inspire you to find your own solution.

Comment: You'd have to know in advance how long it takes to generate a lineup, which may or may not be possible.

Comment: Well considering that the number of players and team stack change daily I don't know if this is gonna be possible.

Comment: Well at least "how many lineups are left to complete" is straightforward, right?